# Why does this curve over $\mathbb{R}$ have no odd degree line bundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

This is in [Moonen's textbook on Abelian Varieties (page 221)](http://van-der-geer.nl/%7Egerard/AV.pdf). My confusion I believe is that I do not understand how to think about $\mathbb{R}$-varieties too well (having only ever worked over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{F}_q$ all my life so far).

It is claimed that the curve $X^2+Y^2+Z^2=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$ has no line bundles of odd degree. However, this curve has no $\mathbb{R}$-points and so a subset of this projective space, it is empty. So there shouldn't be any line bundles whatsoever on it. What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, for one, no $\Bbb R$-points does not imply the empty scheme! You've doubtlessly seen $\Bbb F_q$-schemes with no $\Bbb F_q$ points, for instance.

Comment: @KReiser Ah, of course. Thanks for pointing that out!